# Acessing multiple pojo in single post method in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have three three different POJO files for my spring project. When i am sending data from angular js(which is also coming from different POJO classes) page to spring mvc , my spring post method is taking only one POJO class .Can anyone tell me that how to call multiple POJO classes in single spring post method.In the following controller ,clue,cluelvl and cluedesc are from clueData POJO class and ans is from clueAns POJO .Just tell me how to call multiple POJO inside one post method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAndSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void save(@RequestBody ClueData clueData , ClueAns clueans)
            //,@RequestBody List<ClueTag> clueTagList) 
    {       System.out.println(" Inside saveAndSubmit method ");
            System.out.println("ans:-" +clueans.getAns() );
            System.out.println("clue:-" +clueData.getClue() );
            System.out.println("level:-" +clueData.getClueLvl() );
            System.out.println("clueDESC:-" +clueData.getClueDesc());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should combine `ClueData` and `ClueAns` into a single POJO. Spring is trying to map whole request body to a parameter annotated with `@RequestBody`. From the Spring [spec](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

> The @RequestBody method parameter annotation indicates that a method
>   parameter should be bound to the value of the HTTP request body.

Comment: is there any other method to fix without combining it??

Comment: Hm... you can split them and use @RequestParams... I would not go this way. Combining two pojos is neither hard nor bad